# Get a regular NSString path for UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller

This code:

```
NSString *imageString = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerRefrenceURL];
NSLog(@"%@", imageString);
```

Returns this:

```
assets-library://asset/asset.JPG?id=1000000002&ext=JPG
```

Is there a proper way to convert this into a path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you want to do that? Can't you go through the Assets Library? See [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetsLibrary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722) for details. Upon success, `ALAssetsLibraryAssetForURLResultBlock` will give you an `ALAsset`, which gives you in turn the media that you found in your reference URL.

Comment: As per the [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/assetslibrary/alassetslibrary#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009722)  `ALAssetsLibrary` is now depricated,please use the Photos framework instead.